# Can you use useState hook inside onClick function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have the following code

```
const {checked, setChecked} = useState(false);
<Form.Check type="checkbox"
                    checked={checked}
                    onClick={(e)=>{
                    setChecked(!checked);
 }}/>
```

Every time I click the checkbox, `react-dom.development.js:327 Uncaught TypeError: setChecked is not a function`
error is raised. I would expect it to work thus am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: for rules off hook you can read this 
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can but useState does not return object it retuns array so you need to write

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
```

Answer (score 3):

Refactor

```
const {checked, setChecked} = useState(false);
```

to

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
```